# sqlalchemy error: AmbiguousForeignKeysError Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code for my DB models:

```py
# account_manager.py
class AccountManager(User):
    __tablename__ = 'account_managers'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(Integer())
    collaborators = relationship("CollaboratorUser", back_populates='manager')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'account_manager'
    }

# collaborator_user.py
class CollaboratorUser(User):
    __tablename__ = 'collaborators'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    manager_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('account_managers.id'))
    manager = relationship("AccountManager", back_populates='collaborators', 
        foreign_keys=[manager_id])

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'collaborator'
    }

# user.py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = id_col()
    email = Column(String)
    full_name = Column(String)
    temporary = Column(Boolean)
    type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }
```

When I attempt to load a model, I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: AmbiguousForeignKeysError
>   Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship AccountManager.collaborators - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table

I looked up this error and ever solution I saw had to do with adding the `foreign_keys` parameter to the relationship function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Changed

```py
manager = relationship("AccountManager", back_populates='collaborators', 
        foreign_keys=[manager_id])
```

to

```py
manager = relationship("AccountManager", backref='collaborators', 
        foreign_keys=[manager_id])
```

and removed `collaborators` from `AccountManager`. This will automatically add the `colloaborators` field to `AccountManager`. This seems at odds with the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html), but there you go.